# minimal ubuntu iso

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I'd like to install a mini.iso of ubuntu, in order to customize my tiny dedicated laptop for word processor essentially and a browser to use sometimes.

Due to to the very latest news about a tremendous bug in apt dpkg, I don't know if it is the case(my decision to undergo a net installation after I downloaded the small is of ubuntu.

Sorry for my very poor English

Comment: detected mitm recently and fixed by debian...

Comment: if debian officially declared fixed, trust it. Aycase here you find more opinions around the topic https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "very latest news" about that particular bug ([LP: #1812353](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1812353)) is that it is already fixed in all supported releases of Ubuntu.